# Assuming bad intentions

Tags: discussion, questions

[I have posted a question asking to classify (give a name) for the Youtube banning policy](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/57365/). The moderators have claimed that I have a purpose different from my question and closed the question. So, it seems that I cannot ask questions since you can assume by intentions whenever you like (those losers who address banning policies are always trolls, right?). Thanks for giving me a lesson on morality and logic.

Comment: your question was closed because you're asking us to guess what Youtube's banning policy is. We don't care about "giving you a lesson on morality" or whatever.

Comment: @Sathya I have described the Youtube policy. I have told twice clearly that I need to classify ir rather than guess is. You lie. you give me a lesson every time you mistreat me.

Comment: And you should know the site's scope doesn't extend to classifying policy, rather to help you use YouTube.

Comment: @Sathya That is another question. You should not explain that is it legitimate to apply a false reason just because you see an off-topic.

Comment: The reason is closed as opinion based because you're asking people to classify YouTube policy. I don't see what's the false reason in that.

Comment: So, you mean that `off-topic question = discussion instigation`? I see why you do not see the false reason.

Comment: Questions that solely exist to provoke discussion are off topic, as they generate speculation.  We want definitive, clear-cut answers to the questions that we curate on the site.  Your question is not answerable,  End of story.

Comment: You manipulanipulate now. You have told that I have off-topic because the site's scope is to help use youtube rather than classifying its policies. Now, you talk about off-topic of different (i.e. too broad and discussion inflaming) kind. You substitute the notions to manipulate.

Comment: Your question is not a good fit for this site. Please stop with the ad hominem attacks.

Comment: I have no word for manipulators who label request for reason and logical consequents `ad hominem attacks`.

Comment: Your question is asking about company policy. We do not answer questions about company policy.

Comment: @EightDaysofMalaise You do not make some logic either. The fact that we do not answer company policy questions cannot justify the false reasons, arguments and twists provided to me here. Kan you kill a person who komes with an off-topic? If you do not say that you can do everything with a person asked unsupported question then why do you argument here by off-topic? I have already pointed out in this thread that off-topic is very different from opinion based or too broad. Off-topic does not imply "opinion based" My question was closed as opinon based. One does not imply the other.

Comment: @val That's enough.  Stop and give [this help center](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/behavior) posting a read *again*.  If you continue to insult everyone as you have, you'll be on your way again.

Comment: I have cleared away your other comments where you persist in insulting everyone as that's not the way that you should be treating other users.  Period.

Answer (score 7):

Your question is asking basically this:

> Is what YouTube doing considered hellbanning?

You are asking if an organisation is doing something according to a certain definition, asking us to define, clarify or refute it.

But that is not part of the question scope allowed for the site.

Questions on this site should be about the usage of a web app, not its policies or how they go about enforcing them, or how they are or are not doing something.

As it is, your question is either:

- off topic - Can only be answered by YouTube/Google on what they think they are doing
- primarily opinion based - users may interpret whether or not hellbanning is actually taking place given any number of scenarios

Comment: Nice and calm answer.

Answer (score 5):

I don't think anyone was passing judgement on you, personally, when your question was closed.  The question is not a good fit for the site because, short of having YouTube issue a statement on the matter, there is no way to answer it.

Any answers which would attempt to address the question would likely end up devolving into a back-and-forth discussion involving what we *speculate* the policy is (and whether that is fair, etc.), which does not fit well into the "question and answer" framework for the site.